# Data entry via form in MS-Access - keep field 1 and allow field 2 to be updated multiple times

Tags: ms-access

I have a tote full of product - tote has barcode label (field 1 on form) and each item inside tote has barcode.  I need to scan the tote barcode once and then scan the items (field 2 on form) until the last item is scanned.  Then Hit a key to end that tote entry and move to another tote.  Is this possible?  I need the a new line in datasheet with tote barcode label next to each item scanned.

I have a portion of this figured out - I can successfully get the data to flow to the sheet and maintain field 1 - but I cannot setfocus to field2 - as I enter it field 2 and press enter, it takes me to field 1, when I hit enter again, it then takes me back to field 2 - I need to eliminate that 2nd enter to get back to field 2

```
Private Sub Field1_AfterUpdate()
If Not IsNull(Me.Field1.Value) Then
  Field1.DefaultValue = Me.Field1.Value
  DoCmd.CancelEvent
  Me.Field2.SetFocus
  End If


End Sub
Private Sub Field2_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.CancelEvent
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo NewRecord_Err

 On Error Resume Next
 DoCmd.GoToRecord , """", acNewRec

NewRecord_Exit:
 Exit Sub

NewRecord_Err:
 Beep
 MsgBox Error$
 Resume NewRecord_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into using a master detail form. You can have your tote information in the master form and the item information in the detail form, also called a sub form.

You'll need at least two tables for this. One table for the Tote data, and one table for the Item data. You'll also need to create a relationship between the two tables, on a common field, e.g. ToteId

Your table structure might look something like this:

```
tblTotes
- ToteId (Autonumber)
- ToteBarcode (Text)

tblToteItems
- ItemId (AutoNumber)
- ToteId (Number) --this has a relationship with the ToteId field in the tblTotes
- Itembarcode (Text)
```

Your master form will have the `tblTotes` as record source. and your sub form will have the `tblToteItems` table. You link the sub form to the master form on the `ToteId` field.